# Prove property of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

I was trying to do this problem:

Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_{i+1}\leq a_i+a_j$ for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $a_1+a_2/2+\cdots+a_n/n\geq a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I tried induction; base case is trivial but have no idea what to do next.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I assume that it you meant $a_{i+j}\leq a_i+a_j$

Comment: No, it is not that question.